# Comic where Scrooge McDuck or Donald Duck is facing a chess player that never loses

Tags: story-identification, comics, disney

I'm looking for an old comic with Scrooge McDuck I think, or maybe Donald Duck. I read it in French was I was young (late 80s or beginning of the 90s).

He is facing a chess player, some kind of gigantic mountain man, with a big beard. This man always wins

> because he is so scary and intimidating, with his big scary look, that the player in front of him loses all his confidence and kind of forfeit.

Comment: http://link.library.austintexas.gov/portal/Scrooge-mcduck-and-the-endless-game-Augusto/ktVb5BXNsBU/?

Comment: Dunno about him being intimidating... https://comicvine.gamespot.com/intellectual-176/4005-34136/

Comment: One of my favorite! If I remember correctly, it is about Scrooge Mc Duck making a bet with his rival Flintheart Glomgold. The game is not chess, but a similar game invented for the comics with overly complicated rules that are said to take years to learn.

Comment: Welcome to SFF by the way! I edited the question to hide the spoiler. I am not sure it is necessary for an indentification question, but I enjoyed the ending of the story so much! More importantly, could you edit the question to add in which context (years, country,...) you read that comic. That would help people to answer your question.

Comment: Thx for your help all but it's not Intellectual-176. It could be what you are talking about Taladris but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9):

I remember this one! It wasn't chess though; it was a complex fictional game called *Novgotch*. Scrooge isn't facing the '*gigantic mountain man with a big beard*', but Flintheart Glomgold, while the bearded man is a former Novgotch champion, to which Scrooge turns for help.

[image]

[image]

According to the [I.N.D.U.C.K.S. Disney comics database](https://inducks.org/), in France, [the story](https://inducks.org/story.php?c=D+91340) was published in [Picsou magazine 266](https://inducks.org/issue.php?c=fr%2FPM++266#g) (in 1994) and [Picsou album B 14](https://inducks.org/issue.php?c=fr%2FALPMB+14#eg), as 'La partie de Novogotch'.

Answer (score 4):

There is [this](https://en.chessbase.com/post/friendly-relations-magnus-carlsen-and-donald-duck) recent (2014) Donald Duck encounter with Magnus Carlsen, the world chess champion.

[image: Chess]

However, it's not clear if it was produced in any languages other than Norwegian.

Comment: Thx for your help but that's not what I'm looking for.